# Bash looping through two sets of files

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting

I am trying to write a bash script that can iterate through two folders, and run the files into a python program. The python program takes two input files (corresponding ones from each folder) and outputs a single file.

It looks a bit like this:

```
folder 1/
    Run_1.out
    Run_2.out
    Run_3.out
    ...
folder 2/
    Sym_1.g0.out
    Sym_2.g0.out
    Sym_3.g0.out
    ...
```

The python program takes in corresponding inputs (e.g. `Run_1.out` and `Sym_1.g0.out`) and outputs a file as such:

```
    NOCI.py Run_1.out Sym_1.g0.out outputfile
```

The python program works fine when used via the terminal with a single pair of files, but since I've got 360 pairs I figured I should use a script. So far I've tried writing two for loops, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FILE1=*.out
    FILE2=*.g0.out
    for i in $FILE1
    do
        for j in $FILE2
            do
                NOCI.py $i $j ${i}_${outputfile}
        done
    done
```

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the directory name when you define the files in `FILE1` and `FILE2`?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is the second file always named the same as the first file, substituting `Run` with `Sym`?

Comment: @unxnut: yes the directory names are specified - just didn't include them in the example!

Comment: @AndyDalton: they are both .out files, but are located in the different directories. I could change the file names if that's an issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching `folder 1/Run_1.out` to `folder 2/Sym_1.g0.out`, and so on for 360 pairs:

```
for n in {1..360}
do
    NOCI.py "folder 1/Run_$n.out" "folder 2/Sym_$n.g0.out" outputfile
done
```

Or if the paired files are not in sequential order, you can pick off the `Run_N.out` files and associate a corresponding `Sym_N.g0.out` file:

```
for r in "folder 1/Run_"*.out
do
    n="${r#folder 1/Run_}"; n="${n%.out}"
    s="folder 2/Sym_$n.out"
    NOCI.py "$r" "$s" outputfile
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do this:

```
parallel NOCI.py {1} {2} {1.}{2.}.output ::: Folder1/* ::: Folder2/*
```

It will default to run one job per CPU thread in parallel.

To see what will be run use `--dry-run`:

```
parallel --dry-run NOCI.py {1} {2} {1.}{2.}.output ::: Folder1/* ::: Folder2/*
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons you should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Read the book: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score 0):

`zsh` would be more suited than `bash` for this kind of task:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
files1=(1/*.out(n)) files2=(2/*.go.out(n))
for f1 f2 (${files1:^files2}) NOCI.py $f1 $f2 3/$f1:t:r+$f2:t
```

- `(n)` sorts the globs numerically so they are processed in numerical order (where `Run_10` comes between `Run_9` and `Run_11` instead of between `Run_1` and `Run_2` without it).
- `${array1:^array2}`: zips two arrays
- `$file:t`: tail part of the file (base name)
- `$filr:r`: root part (remove extension).

So we end up running:

```
NOCI.py 1/Run_1.out 2/Sym_1.g0.out 3/Run_1+Sym_1.g0.out
NOCI.py 1/Run_2.out 2/Sym_2.g0.out 3/Run_2+Sym_2.g0.out
...
```